# How to convert from arraylist to array

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, arraylist

I have three methods that sorts which are `sortTitle()`, `sortYear()`, `sortSinger()`. All of them are in `arraylist` form as in they will sort an `arraylist` but my teacher said I need it in regular `array` form. I fixed up my whole program but this part I don't know how I would make it into regular or what things I would have to change. Here are the methods.

```
public static void sortTitles(ArrayList<Music2> music)
    {
       int y;
       Music2 temp = new Music2("",0,"");

       for(int x = 1; x<music.size(); x++)
       {
            temp.equals(music.get(x));
            y=0;
            for( y = x; y > 0; y--)
            {    
                if(temp.getTitle().compareTo(music.get(y-1).getTitle()) < 0)
                    music.get(y).equals(music.get(y-1));    
                else
                    break;
            }
            music.get(y).equals(temp);

       }      
    }    

    public static void sortSingers(ArrayList<Music2> music)
    {
       int y;
       Music2 temp = new Music2("",0,"");

       for(int x = 1; x<music.size(); x++)
       {
            temp.equals(music.get(x));
            y=0;
            for( y = x; y > 0; y--)
            {    
                if(temp.getSinger().compareTo(music.get(y-1).getSinger()) < 0)
                    music.get(y).equals(music.get(y-1));    
                else
                    break;
            }
            music.get(y).equals(temp);

       }      
    }

    public static void sortYears(ArrayList<Music2> music)
    {
       int y;
       Music2 temp = new Music2("",0,"");

       for(int x = 1; x<music.size(); x++)
       {
            temp.equals(music.get(x));
            y=0;
            for( y = x; y > 0; y--)
            {    
                if(temp.getYear() < music.get(y-1).getYear())
                    music.get(y).equals(music.get(y-1));    
                else
                    break;
            }
            music.get(y).equals(temp);

       }      
    }
```

Comment: [`List#toArray`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#toArray%28%29)

Comment: What's the problem you are having? Change the method to take a `Music2[]` and change the access to `myArray[i]` rather than `myArrayList.get(i)`. On another note, if you're copy and pasting the same code into 3 places and changing one line you should realise that something is wrong. Maybe take a look at how `Arrays.sort` does it, using a `Comparator` as a callback.

Comment: Just change every reference to the ArrayList for a reference to an array and every `add` and `get` for the corresponding array[index].

Comment: That doesn't help too much. It doesn't tell me if what i would need to change and stuff and I changed my arraylist that holds all the names and stuff to array I need to change just these methods. @mre

Comment: What about the .size()? @BoristheSpider

Comment: What's wrong with `.length`?

Comment: @user2443602, I answered the question. It's up to you to figure out how to implement it.

Comment: How would i change the `.size` @BoristheSpider

Comment: If you are sorting then you don't need to.

Comment: But it shows an error on that. It says "Cannot find symbol"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static void sortYears(Music2[] musics)
{
   int y;
   Music2 temp = new Music2("",0,"");

   for(int x = 0; x<musics.length; x++)
   {
        for( y = 1; y < musics.length-x; y++)
        {    
            if(musics[x].getYear() > musics[y-1].getYear()) {
                swap(x, y, musics);
            }
        }
   }      
}

private static void swap(int a, int b, Object[] arr) {
    Object temp = arr[a];
    arr[a] = arr[b];
    arr[b] = temp;
}
```

Thats 1 you can do the rest.